# C# - Throw an exception if can't connect to remote server

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to get an exception thrown if the function in my method fails, my code is as follows so far:

```
 if (sourceFile.Exists)
            // Would be nice to add ticker / spinner, while the file header on the remote server is being read!!
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://google.com/test.zip");
                request.Method = "HEAD";
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                if (response.LastModified > sourceFile.LastWriteTime)
                {

                    Download_Click(sender, e);

                    // use response.GetStream() to download the file.
                }
```

Comment: @ba__friend How can I catch an exception, if no network connectivity is available

Comment: Don't help, it already happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) docs, a [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) is thrown from `GetResponse` if the request times out or another error occurs while processing it.

You should be able to catch that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

try/catch HttpException

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.aspx